# TTL on table: what about updates?

Tags: scylla

I have a table in which rows must expire after a month or so. When a row is created, it can be updated. I was curious if the update would bypass the TTL and would exist forever, since the update does not contain any TTL. This is what the docs are saying:

https://docs.scylladb.com/stable/cql/time-to-live.html

> Here a TTL of 10 minutes is applied to all rows, however, keep in mind
> that TTL is stored on a per column level for non-primary key columns.

I don't understand what this means. What does setting a TTL means for primary key columns? I just want my rows to be deleted after a certain time.

My question is: will an insert/update without TTL overwrite the tables TTL? Will setting a TTL simply delete the row after a certain time? Will the TTL reset for the row after an update statement (without ttl)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and answering it accurately requires some subtleties.

First you need to know that in CQL, the expiration time is stored together with each *cell* (column value), not for an entire row. So if you INSERT a row with a=1, b=2 and c=3 with some TTL X, the TTL isn't stored once for the entire row - rather, each of the three columns will be stored with TTL X separately. If you later UPDATE only column a with TTL Y, you'll now have the a value expiring at one time and b and c expiring at a different time (this is fine for CQL - you are allowed to have a row where some of its columns are undefined (*null*)). If you update a column without specifying the TTL, the new value will never expire - it will not remember the previous TTL.

You may be asking yourself why doesn't updating one column (or all of the columns) of an existing row just keep the previous TTL value. Well, this is because one of the design goals of Scylla (and Cassandra) is to make writes are fast as possible. Scylla does writes fast precisely because it **does not** need to read the old value first. When you update x=1 Scylla just writes down that update ("mutation"), and doesn't need to read the previous value. Scylla will only needs to reconcile the different versions of the value (the one with the highest timestamp wins) during read or on a special "compaction" step that happens periodically. With this in mind, when you set x=1 with TTL y (or if TTL not set at all, infinity), this will be the new value of this column - the older TTL value isn't available during this update.

To answer your question about primary keys there's something else you need to know: In CQL, a row "exists" by virtue of having some live **non-key** columns. For example if your primary key is p, when you insert p=1,x=2 you basically inserting x=2 (non-key) into the row at p=1. If the x=2 expires, the entire row disappears. That's why the TTL is relevant only to non-key columns.

Well, I actually cheated a little bit in the last paragraph, and there's another subtlety here that I didn't explain. Maybe you noticed that it is possible to INSERT a row and then use UPDATE to delete each one of its columns individually, and you are left with an *empty* row, which still exists but is empty. How does this work, when I said that a row needs non-key cells to exist? Well, the trick is that the INSERT not only adds the specific columns you asked for (x=2), it also adds another invisible empty-named column (called the "CQL row marker"). When you later delete the individual columns, the row-marker column remains undeleted and keeps the row alive. When you INSERT a row with a TTL x, this command not only sets the TTL of each specified column to x, it also sets the TTL of the hidden row-marker column to x, so when x comes the entire row disappears because all its columns (including the row-marker column) have disappeared. Note that only INSERT, not UPDATE, adds this row marker. This means that if you want to change the TTL of the row marker, you must do this by doing an INSERT, not an UPDATE. For example, if you INSERT data with TTL x, and later UPDATE overwriting all its columns to an earlier expiration time, you'll end up with the data columns expiring early but the row marker remaining until its original expiration - and until then an empty row is visible.